# REST API to add data into a data extension leads to error 20002

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, dataextensions, marketingcloudapi

I am using a REST API to add data into a data extension and I receive the following error:

```
{
"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete this action.",
"errorcode": 20002,
"documentation": ""
}
```

This API was configured around 2 months ago and it was working fine that time. In between I am not sure if I made some changes unknowingly.
Please help me to resolve this error at the earliest.

Comment: It means the permissions for your Installed Package are insufficient for your request.  The permissions for your call are returned when you request a token.

Comment: also verify the scope you are passing has not changed. Even if the package has the permissions, if you pass a scope that does not have the correct permission set, it will toss the error as well. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked with Adam Spriggs solution for me.